# How to use Jenkins pipeline to update a website on another server?

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline

I've setup and connected a Jenkins (2.249) server to my GitHub account, so it has access to my repos and I've setup the GitHub webhook.

But I am having problems trying to understand how to create a multibranch pipeline job to detect when a push to my master branch happens and then I want to run SSH commands on another host to update a web server with the new code changes.

With Jenkins pipelines, I can't see how to detect when a push to master happens and then trigger the build? Is this possible with Jenkins? I have Blue Ocean installed as well.

Answer (score 1):

Multi-branch Pipeline jobs periodically check the server for updates. It sets an environment variable `BRANCH_NAME` with the current branch during execution.

If you only care about the master branch, you should use a regular Pipeline job that only watches master.

See [the docs](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/multibranch/)